# seeming ugly limit

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math

i want to compute the limit

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^6}{720}}{x^7}$$

Instead of doing some messy calculation, I think if there is some ingenious way to compute this limit, but i don't know how to do. thank you so much.

Comment: You know the Taylor series of $e^x$?

Comment: What's messy about applying l'Hopital seven times?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hints:

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots\implies$$

$$e^x-1-x-\ldots-\frac{x^6}{6!}=\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}+O(x^9)\implies$$

$$\frac{e^x-1-x-\ldots-\frac{x^6}{6!}}{x^7}=\frac1{7!}+\frac{x}{8!}+O(x^2)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\;?$$

Answer (score 6):

Apply the L'Hôpital rule $7$ times (until the derivatives *kill* the polynomial $1+x+\ldots+\frac{x^6}{6!}$) and we find

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^6}{720}}{x^7}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x}{7!}=\frac{1}{7!}$$